# Model data not recieving on Server on put call in backbone.js?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I am trying to save a model to the server from backbone.js. My problem is when I make a post call, all the model values are recieved on server successfully, but I make a put call on the server after setting model id. It makes call sucessfully but I recived not model values on the server although model is filled with values on the client side. I am using follwing code. Please guide

```
        var isAdd = false;
            if (e.insuranceId != 0) {
                this.model.id = e.insuranceId;
                isAdd = false;
            } else
                isAdd = true;
            this.model.set('PatientId', this.options.patientId);

             this.model.save({}, {
                success: function (model, resp) {
                    console.log('success');
                    if(isAdd)
                    self.model.set(self.model.defaults);
                    self.insuranceId = model.attributes.PatientInsuranceId;;
                    self.saveFrontImageDB();
                    self.showConfirmation();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Are you sure no data is getting sent? Have you used any browser dev tools (like firebug) to validate that data is indeed not being sent?

Comment: Yes I am pretty much sure as I am working on it. I am getting no data except id of the model on server side while it is making successful server side call.

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of  debugging and untiring effort I figured out problem. There was a problem of mapping between server side model and client side model.

Comment: Can you explain the issue and *how* you resolved the issue a bit more, for the benefit of future readers who may have a similar issue?

Comment: Hi, I serialized model collection at client side in js file and send it to server and received at server in iCollection object with same properties.